# Seeking USA CLU shapefiles for agricultural land?

Tags: data, united-states

I know [Is geocomm.com permanently unavailable?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240246) was asked a few days back and is closed. That is the site I was hoping to buy from initially.

[Data providers equivalent to USDA/NRCS/FSA Common Land Unit (CLU)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89767) from 3 years also points to the geocomm site (which is now defunct).

Is it possible to find the 2008 FSA version of the CLU data which was the last version that was publicly available?

Answer (score 2):

FSA's Common Land Unit data contains personally identifiable information, therefore it is not available to the public. For an up-to-date data source, you should check for parcel data from the County Assessor for your area of interest.

Answer (score 0):

We have CLU data with full attribution to the owners and operators which is updated.  We have also linked it with weather, watershed and soils and imagery.

Comment: Steve, can you post a site link where I can go take a look and maybe contact you?

Comment: @nmctech Take a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/242169/64785

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same snag, after purchasing the data for Ohio back in 2015. I was very upset when I found this site is now down, RIGHT when I finally decide I need the full data too. Bummer.

Answer (score -1):

You can obtain (via bulk download) the last released 2008 files here for free from Cornell University, Ag-Analtyics.Org

https://www.ag-analytics.org/BulkData/CLU_US

There is a readme in that directory with other info as well.

We also have them available for query via our API. Please contact us at jdw277@cornell.edu if you want to access them that way.

Here are the citations to include please:

"FSA Common Land Units obtained via Ag-Analytics.Org (Woodard,2016a; Woodard, 2016b)" or similar with the following references:

1.) Woodard, J.D., “Big data and Ag-Analytics: an open source, open data platform for agricultural & environmental finance, insurance, and risk,” Agricultural Finance Review, (2016) 76(1):15-26. 2.) Woodard, J.D., “Data Science and Management for Large Scale Empirical Applications in Agricultural and Applied Economics Research,” Applied Economic Perspectives and Policy, (2016) 38(3): 373-388.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Please don't just repost the exact same answer multiple times (on the same or different questions).  If there is an answer already given on another Q&A please vote/flag as a duplicate or comment with a link to that answer rather than reposting the same thing.  Additionally please take note of our self-promotion policy  - [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior), in particular the note about disclosure